# Chart not displaying on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am currently using angular-charts in my application. I created a line chart which worked perfectly, however when adding a second chart (pie) the first chart does not show on the front end until I either hovered over it or resize the window.

I have no hover events set so I am unsure why this is happening.

Here is my controller

```
app.controller('dashboardController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Page', 'authenticationService', function ($scope, $http, Page, authenticationService) {

// Page Setup
Page.setTitle('Dashboard');
Page.setSubTitle('Transport Overview');
$scope.$emit('pageLoading');

$http({
    url: '/api/dashboard/',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: authenticationService.getAuthToken(),
}).success(function (data) {

    $scope.dashboard = data;
    $scope.dashboard.revenuePerDayLabels = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    $scope.dashboard.weeklyJobIncome = [data.weeklyJobIncome];
    $scope.dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueLabels = [];
    $scope.dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueData = [];

    angular.forEach($scope.dashboard.weekVehicleRevenue, function (item) {
        $scope.dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueLabels.push(item.registrationNumber);
        $scope.dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueData.push(item.vehicleRevenue);
    });

    $scope.$emit('pageLoaded');
}).error(function () {
    $scope.$emit('pageLoaded');
});
}]);
```

***And the corresponding HTML***

**Line Chart**

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"
        chart-data="dashboard.weeklyJobIncome"
        chart-labels="dashboard.revenuePerDayLabels"
        chart-series="series">
</canvas>
```

**Pie Chart**

```
<canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-pie"
        chart-data="dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueData"
        chart-labels="dashboard.weekVehicleRevenueLabels">
</canvas>
```

[image: Canvas is being rendered]

Comment: Does the console show any errors on page load?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/29 there are quite a few solutions that people have had success with

Comment: I hadn't no, looking at it, it the issue I am facing here.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around the issue by using the following line of code. Its a bit hacky, but it works in this situation.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: credit: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/29#issuecomment-81541417